# No shared cipher suites on linux

Tags: node.js, ssl, encryption, server, openssl

I have created a tls server with nodeJS. If I start the server on a windows machine the server client connection work's perfect.
I I start the server on linux machine the following error appears:

```
Error: 140206047820672:error:1408A0C1:SSL routines:ssl3_get_client_hello:no shared cipher:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s3_srvr.c:1427:

at _tls_wrap.js:184:18
at loadSession (_tls_wrap.js:103:5)
at TLSSocket.onclienthello (_tls_wrap.js:180:3)
at TLSWrap.ssl.onclienthello (_tls_wrap.js:451:50)
```

How can I solve this problem beacause I need the connectio on a linux machine?

The OpenSSL version is 1.1.0f both.

Comment: The Linux machine doesn't have a server private key or certificate.

Comment: Hmm that's strange because I have a trusted key and a trusted cert on the server.

Comment: IMHO the message `no shared cipher`  means intompatible or limited ciphersuit (or tls version). try to find a set of supported tls version and cipher suites on the server and supported by the client

Answer (score 1):

I just solved this issue for my environment.  OP doesn't mention what the client implementation is, but the issue for me was the nodejs grpc client.  It simply just didn't seem to support the ciphers that were on the server end, no matter what, e.g.:

```
# this didn't work for me:
export GRPC_SSL_CIPHER_SUITES="HIGH+ECDSA"
```

Updating grpc to @grpc/grpc-js made the issue go away.

```
npm i @grpc/grpc-js
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@grpc/grpc-js describes the gotchyas involved with the upgrade from the deprecated npm package.